# Regular Expression that contains 1 to 3 members of a set but one of those members cannot be by itself

Tags: javascript, regex

Here's my current regular expression:

```
([\d\*]{1,3}[A-Z\*]{0,3})
```

My problem is with the first portion `[\d\*]{1,3}` I need this to match at most 3 numbers and at least one number and I need to accept the wild card input too - **BUT the wild card character (*) cannot be on its owns** which is what this would currently allow is some situations.

So I need the first portion to match:

```
123
12*
*23
1*
*2
1*3
```

But not just:

```
*
```

Comment: @m is that all present in a single line?

Comment: Is `"***"` valid ? Is `"1**"` ?

Comment: is this actually a comma separated string?

Comment: multiple `*` strung together should be treated as if it were one

Comment: its not comma separated its just free form

Comment: @m.e.conroy Meaning 1****3 is valid ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use positive lookaround assertions.

```
^(?!\*+$)[\d\*]{1,3}[A-Z\*]{0,3}$
```

`(?!\*+$)` negative lookahead which asserts that the string going to  match won't contain only `*`'s.

**OR**

```
^(?=.*\d)[\d\*]{1,3}[A-Z\*]{0,3}$
```

`(?=.*\d)` positive lookahead which asserts that the string going to be match must contain atleast one digit character.

[DEMO](https://regex101.com/r/iX0hS5/2)

Comment: are look aheads and look behinds supported in javascript?

Comment: js supports lookaheads but not lookbehinds.

Comment: Excellent, thank you.  Never knew of that regex101 site, that is awesome

Answer (score 1):

You can do this:

```
(([\d\*]{2,3}|\d)[A-Z\*]{0,3})
```

Comment: but this won't match `*23`

Comment: That wouldn't allow for the wild card being the first character, for example: `*23`

Comment: @AvinashRaj Oh, yes, I have misunderstand some part of the requirement

Comment: That would allow `**` though, which is the same as `*`

Comment: sorry didn't see your other comment before I wrote mine

Answer (score 1):

A basic way: *(I assumed only one `*` is allowed)*:

```
((?:\d(?:[\d*]?\d?|\d\*?)|\*\d\d?)[A-Z*]{0,3})
```

Note that this pattern must be anchored to something.